# Scrapy correct xpath for unnamed div with image and text

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a Spider that traverses through several paginated pages and extracts data from the site:
http://www.usnews.com/education/best-global-universities/neuroscience-behavior

This is the spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html
from usnews.items import UsnewsItem


class UniversitiesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "universities"
    allowed_domains = ["usnews.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.usnews.com/education/best-global-universities/neuroscience-behavior/',
        )

    #Rules = [
    #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('.//a[@class="pager_link"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True)
    #]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('.//div[@class="sep"]'):
            item = UsnewsItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('.//h2[@class="h-taut"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['location'] = sel.xpath('.//span[@class="t-dim t-small"]/text()').extract()
            item['ranking'] = sel.xpath('.//div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract()
            item['score'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="t-large t-strong t-constricted"]/text()').extract()
            #print(sel.xpath('.//text()').extract()
            yield item
```

I am having problems extracting the text for the item "ranking". According to google chomes xpath suggestion the xpath is: `//*[@id="resultsMain"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]` which gives me the single number for the first entry and a bunch of empty values. It seems to be implemented inside an img tag and I am confused on how to access it to just extract the thext (for example #1, #22 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath should find `div` containing `img` child, and then return non-empty text node child which contains the 'ranking' :

```
for sel in response.xpath('.//div[@class="sep"]'):
    ...
    item['ranking'] = sel.xpath('div/div[img]/text()[normalize-space()]').extract()
```